# How do i backup whole hard drive?

Tags: windows-xp, backup, nas

I have a iomega iconnect nas and i am thinking of backing up my whole hard drive.

There are two choices using windows file sharing or rsync.

I tried to google and people is saying it is unsafe to share out whole hard drive but i cant find any detail steps. anyone can advise?

And if i using rsync what sofware i need to install in windows xp to do so

Answer (score 2):

I know this isn't exactly what you are asking for, but you might have better luck with a Drive Imaging software like Acronis True Image Home, DriveImage XML or Macrium Reflect Backup. That will allow you to guarantee a *full* copy of your hard drive and make it easier to restore your machine in case of a failure.

If you would still prefer to use a file based solution - I would recommend looking into FreeFileSync, SyncToy v2.0, or Unison File Synchronizer - these have native Windows support rather than trying to find an rsync utility for Win32/64.

Comment: Also take a look at Drive Snapshot, which is ShareWare with a free 30-day trial (for making backups only; reading/restoring is free forever regardless of trial status); it has some excellent features such as mounting the snapshot as a drive letter, and it also reports any bad sectors in a plain/text file as it encounters them:  http://www.drivesnapshot.de/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Seagate or Maxtor hard drive, you can get a free copy of the Original Equipment Manufacturer (OEM) version of Acronis True Image. Seagate provides this tool for migrating your files from an older Seagate or Maxtor hard disk to a new one. You can also use the tool as backup utilities simply by downloading either the [Seagate DiscWizard](http://www.seagate.com/www/en-us/support/downloads/discwizard) or [Maxtor MaxBlast](http://www.seagate.com/ww/v/index.jsp?locale=en-US&name=MaxBlast_5&vgnextoid=7add8b9c4a8ff010VgnVCM100000dd04090aRCRD) software.

After you download and install either of these OEM version packages, you’ll be able to quickly and easily create a complete image backup of your Windows XP hard disk.

I've also read good things about [HDCLONE](http://www.miray.de/products/sat.hdclone.html) which also does disk imaging and there's a free version.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [cwRsync](http://www.itefix.no/i2/node/10650) for years with great success.  It is a self-contained windows version of rSync.  The same site also has another package for a rSync server if you need that, too.

Answer (score 0):

I have had great luck with CopyTo Synchronizer, now freeware:
http://www.kish-d.com/

It is highly customizable with name, date, and size filters, supports one way or two way synchronization, gives a summary of files to be synced before it runs, and is very low-overhead.